# How to make the following recursion faster?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
long long int num(int n,int m)
{
    long long int k,i;

    k=0;

    if(n>1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
        {
            k+=((p[i]%MOD)*(num(n-1,i)%MOD))%MOD;
            k%=MOD;
        }

        return k;
    }
    else
        return q[m];
}
```

The code above is in C , I need to make this run faster , the arrays p[i],q[i] are global values and so is MOD , is there any way i can make it faster , may be by storing values or something . I think DP can be used be here , but i am not sure of the approach .

as i was asked to post p[i] and q[i] and MOD ,here they are MOD =1000000000 , always .

```
void seive(int c)
{
    long long int i,temp;

    p[0]=1;
    q[0]=p[0];
    for(i=c+1;i<=(2*c+2);i++)
    {
        temp=((p[i-c-1]%MOD)*(c%MOD))%MOD;
        temp/=(i-c);

        p[i-c]=((p[i-c-1]%MOD)+(temp%MOD))%MOD;
        q[i-c]=((q[i-c-1]%MOD)+(p[i-c]%MOD))%MOD;

    }
}
```

c=m-1 (the m in the first code and c in the second code are related)

Comment: The best optimization operator for C99 is `//` :-)

Comment: It can be ordered by increasing `n`, that's really all there is to it. As a nice bonus, you only have to remember the previous row, not all preceding rows.

Comment: post the definitions of `p`,  `q` and `MOD`.  If the type is not `long long int p[]`, you could change the type of `k` with potential efficiency improvement.

Comment: `i` should be declared `int`.

Comment: i added the defination of p,q and MOD .

Comment: Since num(n, *) is a linear combination of num(n-1, *), you can use matrix multiplication and fast exponentiation to compute the first m members of num(n, *) in time O(log n * m^3)

Answer (score 0):

Declare global 2D- Array.

Since MOD is not changing initially calculate p[i]=p[i]%MOD

% operation is costly

```
  long long temp[][];   // size can be max value of n and m  and initialize to LLONG_MIN

 long long int num(int n,int m) {

  long long int k,i;

  k=0;

 if(n>1)
 {
        for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
        {
              int h=0;
               if(temp[n-1][i]!= LLONG_MIN){
                 h=temp[n-1][i];
                }else{
                 temp[n-1][i]= num(n-1,i)%MOD;
                 h=temp[n-1][i];
                }
                k+=((p[i])*(h))%MOD;
                k%=MOD;
        }

        return k;
}

else
        return q[m];

}
```

Comment: I think that the `%MOD` can further be removed from `k+=((p[i])*(h))%MOD;` as `k%=MOD;` directly follows (unless `MOD>LLONG_MAX/2`).